# Uploading multiples files in CodeIgniter using plain PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I am new to CodeIgniter. I've tried uploading my files using as follows:

**(createAlbum.php)**

```
<form method="post" action="createAlbum_db.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Album Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="album_name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Photos for album: </td><td><input type = "file" name="photos[]" multiple="true"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Create Album"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**(createAlbum_db.php)**

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['photos']['name']);$i++) {
    if (move_uploaded_file(base_url().'assets/images/'.$_FILES['photos']['name'][$i],$_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
        echo '<br>success';
    } else {
        echo '<br>Failure';
        echo $_FILES['photos']['error'][$i];
    }
}
```

My assets directory lies in the same directory where application and system files reside.
What I am not being able to figure out is what should I keep in 
`move_uploaded_file(**DESTINATION????**,$_FILE['photos']['tmp_name']);`

I have gone through most of the post and I found CodeIgniter's native uploader class difficult to use.

Comment: thanks Mihai Iorga. any suggestions for above problem?

Answer (score 0):

Codi. provides upload function for that

```
    <?php
      $config['upload_path'] = // Here Goes Path;
      $config['allowed_types'] = // Here Goes allowed file types;
      $config['max_size'] = // you can validate max. size;
      $config['max_width']  = '';
      $config['max_height']  = '';
      $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
      $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

      $this->load->library('upload', $config);
      if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
      {
          echo $this->upload->display_errors();
      }
      else
      {
          $img =    $this->upload->data();
          $img_name = $img['file_name'];
      }

    ?>
```

Just Like this, you can upload single file....

Answer (score 0):

Since you need path on server use `realpath('assets/images/')` instead of `base_url()`.